# What is the English word used to describe something like m/s or m/s/s ?

Tags: science, measuring-units

In science, some quantities have *units*. e.g. *Mass* (`kg`) , *time* (`s`), *distance* (`m`).

But what about quantities such as velocity (`m/s`) and acceleration (`m/s/s`) whose units are a combination of fundamental units and not a single unique unit.

What is the correct English term for something like `m/s` ? Is it a **unit** or not, or is there another word to describe such combination of units?

I'm looking for a one-word answer. 
The ... of velocity is m/s.

Comment: Welcome. You could have answered this easily by Googling 'unit of velocity' . Then you would have found something like this, ***The SI unit of distance and displacement is the meter. The SI unit of time is the second. The SI unit of speed and velocity is the ratio of two — the meter per second.*** http://physics.info/velocity/

Comment: Velocity is expressed in units of distance divided by time.

Comment: It's not really a subject for this site, but you should look up "fundamental units of measurement". Velocity can be expressed as a combination of fundamental units, therefore doesn't 'deserve' such a unit of its own.

Comment: I've voted to close. This  question could have been answered with easily available online resources.

Comment: @JHCL - Velocity can be expressed as a fraction of C, a fundamental constant.

Comment: @HotLicks - You're right of course; you can *define* your units using physical constants, but you have to start somewhere. The SI unit of *distance* is defined by c.  Meanwhile, from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre_per_second): "The *benz*, named in honour of Karl Benz, has been proposed as a name for one metre per second.[2] Although it has seen some support as a practical unit, primarily from German sources, it was rejected as the SI unit of velocity and has not seen widespread use or acceptance."

Comment: @JHCL - I propose the "HotLicks" as a unit -- one millionth of the value of C.

Comment: @JHCL And I would like to propose *the volkswagen* as the ratio of actual emissions to tested emissions.

Comment: As any fule kno, the correct unit for speed is the [attoparsec per microfortnight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_humorous_units_of_measurement).

Comment: This belongs on [physics.se].

Answer (score 2):

The technical term for this is a *derived unit*, but in everyday speak/text I think using the word *unit* is totally acceptable.

See for example the Wikipedia page ab out [SI Derived Units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_derived_unit).

Comment: Of course, what's "derived" is more a matter of culture than fact.  Velocity can be expressed as a fraction of C, the speed of light, which is a fundamental constant and which is used in most modern schemes to accurately determine time and distance.

Comment: Although I've voted to close, I think this answer does provide useful background information.  I'll just add that many named units (e,g, the herz) are actually derived  units. One hertz is one cycle per second.  The  truth is that any unit at all can be derived from a combination of other units. (as hinted at by HotLicks' comment)

Comment: The whole bit about "I think" and "everyday speak" is completely uncalled for weasel wording. If the technical term is *derived unit*, then that is a unit *by definition*. The name says just that. What do you mean "I think", "perhaps", "in everyday text"? You yourself only just said that *unit* was in fact the perfectly proper technical term and now you're backing down? Why?

Comment: @RegDwigнt I don't see which part of my answer was unclear... I noted the term (_derived unit_) which is the correct one, and noted that another term (_unit_) - which is a superset of the first - can also be used. What are you upset about?